# Unable to resolve some modules: "./style" when i import React-Toolbox component

Tags: reactjs

I start making a new interface with react-toolbox. and this is just my first step and i face this problem. I got an message in my console:

> Unable to resolve some modules: "./style" ...
>   i don't know why the style won't load. i also imported its component already.
>   here are some simple code :

```
import React from 'react';

import {Button} from 'react-toolbox';

class MyButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button icon='bookmark' label='Bookmark' raised primary />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default MyButton;
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Did you follow the install instructions? http://react-toolbox.com/#/install Do you have babel / css and sass loaders?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @QoP I used to see it.. i don't really know how to use webpack

Comment: @azium What are they? So i need to load the styles? How to get started with it? Which one should i use?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because react-toolbox uses CSS Modules and you dont have the loaders to preprocess them.

You are going to need

[webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack)

[css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader)

[style-loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader)

Comment: what is about scss loader? It is the same as css-loader?

Comment: do you mean sass-loader? there is no scss loade

Comment: yes! do you have any documentation about how to use webpack css-loader and style-loader? I can't find them.